# jquery $(this) - how to access child h2

Tags: jquery, html

I've got this HTML structure:

```
 <span id="subMenuTitle1" class="subMenuClickAble"><h2>Inbox 1</h2></span>
```

I want to attached a click event to span.subMenuClickAble and extra the text() in the h2.

I've tried to the following:

```
 var text = $(this).child('h2').text();

 var text = $(this h2).text();
```

Any advise?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com -- Check-Out the docs. Make sure you are using methods that actually exist.

Comment: @João - I'm thinking _extract_

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/children/ -- why did you try `.child` at all? It does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = $('h2', this).text();
```

However, your HTML code is invalid (unless you are using HTML 5 and targetting only HTML 5 capable browsers), so the `h2` element might not even end up inside the `span` tag.

An inline element (`span`) may not contain a block element (`h2`). Browsers will try to correct the code, usually by moving the `h2` element outside the `span`, or ending the `span` element where the `h2` element starts.

Comment: great call - just tested on a html4 browser and the span/h2 isn't holding format... will adjust this... thx for the code... will tick once time expires... cheers

Answer (score 2):

use [jquery find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var text = $(this).find('h2').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#subMenuTitle1').click(function (event) {
    var text = $(this).children('h2').text();
    /* do stuff here */
});​
```

Edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtf7g/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.subMenuClickAble').click(function(){
    console.log( $(this).find('h2').text() );
})
```